# How can I give input files for cuda parallel programming?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, product, dot

I have to implement vector dot product in CUDA parallel programming model to make use of GPUs for computing. I will test my code by input files, which has two vectors to be multiplied. How can I give input files in cuda parallel programming for this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA is an extension of C/C++. There is no special way to provide input to CUDA ( It does not even make sense said this way).

You first need to read the files like you would normally do in C/C++ and then use CUDA API to transfer the data to the GPU using `cudaMemCpy` for instance. Once you are finished with it you can transfer it back to the CPU side.